# WebStorm is not breaking long lines

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

I am currently using WebStorm 2019.3.4 and in an Angular project, I cannot break long lines when try to reformat code pressing <kbd>CTRL + ALT + L</kbd>.

I have the default configuration for the IDE and TypeScript.

Example of long line I want to break:

```
export const countyList = [{
   countyName: 'Alachua',
   taxRate: '0.01',
   zipCodeList: ['32601', '32602', '32603', '32604', '32605', '32606', '32607', '32608', '32609', '32610', '32611', '32612', '32613', '32614', '32615', '32616', '32618', '32627', '32631', '32635', '32641', '32643', '32653', '32654', '32655', '32658', '32662', '32667', '32669', '32694']
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default formatting behavior for arrays is not to wrap them. You can configure it yourself using this set of options:

[image: options]

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much.